# IOS Contacts Smart Search like Android

Tags: android, ios, algorithm, logic

I am working on an iOS smart dialer app using ionic framework (AngularJS) in which I am in need of contacts smart search. I am sure I need to write an algorithm for smart search. I've searched the internet and found nothing regarding this. What is the best approach for this?

If I tap on `1` and `2`, I should get contacts searched with combination of `ad`, `ae`, `af`, `bd`, `be`, `bf`, `cd`, `ce`, `cf`.

Please help me if there is any easy and fast way to search contacts.

Comment: Is this about iOS or Android? Update your tags and title accordingly.

Comment: its for both , I already got the object with contacts and able to search using some string. I am developing this app for both android and ios using ionic framework and cordova

Comment: The title says "Android". The question says "iOS". It's confusing.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, Android has this feature already but ios doesn't.  for better understanding please visit the following 
[link](https://lh3.ggpht.com/bw1w3OjoBFuxVtCWzf1_FkMJ-HVVS6yg92XY5vbNoiJB4yfv-NDVn8q4iOcAhLv4zD4=w520)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called T9 search algorithm.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a bit more?